# kendo angular 2 installation error - Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

During installation of Kendo angular 2, while trying to enable the Progress NPM registry on my machine by running:

```
npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress
```

After I entered my name, password & email I got:

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "login" "--registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/" "--scope=@progress"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9

npm ERR! Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
npm ERR! The page was not displayed because there was a conflict.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\wamp64\www\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: What username did you enter? It should be the same as your e-mail, without the @ and domain part.

Comment: I indeed used the wrong login. When I entered the right one, it ended successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`username:` type in everything before the `@` if it is an email address.

`password:` *yourpassword*

`Email (this IS public)`: for the first time enter `%40` instead of `@`
in username.

It will say `npm WARN Email must be an email address`

then type your e-mail again normally (using proper `@`)

Worked for me.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/npm#kendo-ui-professional

Comment: There should be no need to enter an encoded e-mail, the vanilla one should work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer / cause described in Drzewiecki's answer was not the solution for me .

This error message was displayed simply because I typed my password wrong .